# KRL email handler

Tags: krl

I've heard it mentioned that each KRL ruleset can have an email address associated with it, allowing the ruleset to respond to mail events (such as mail received). What is the format of that email address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation on the email endpoint can be found at http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Email_Endpoint

The format of the email for each app is

```
{appid}[.dev][+{label}]@kynetxapps.net
```

The simplest example if your app id is a60x42

```
a60x42@kynetxapps.net
```

Comment: to clarify Mike's syntax, the .dev is optional, as is the+label. The simplest form is {appid}@kynetxapps.net. Adding .dev runs the dev version of your rule, and the label is available as an event:param() and within the selection expression.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @TelegramSam. Looks like a good thing to do a kynetxappaday post on.

Comment: Second the motion. A thorough example would be very useful!